Technical question about computing the left ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
Computing the left ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. This is the same that computing the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, but in order to solve this problem I've tried a Lam's result that can be found in Proposition 1.17 pages 17-18 from "A first course in non-commutative rings" that states that the ring ($\mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$) is basically the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$ And that the left ideals for this ring are $I_{1} \oplus I_{2}$, where $I_{2}$ is a left ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $I_{1}$ is a left  $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.
(Step 1) Computing $I_{2}$
This is not rocket science since the only ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ are $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ itself. Therefore, $I_{2}$ is $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.
(Step 2) Computing $I_{1}$.
This is going to be trickier since we need to compute the submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ that contain $\mathbb{Z}_{2} I_{2}$. By step (1) we have that $I_{2} = 0$ or $I_{2} = \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}_{2} I_{2}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}0=0$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \mathbb{Z}_{2} = \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. On the one hand,  for the submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \mathbb{Z}_{2} = \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ we got just  $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. On the other hand, the left $\mathbb{Z}_{2} $ submodules containing  $ \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ are $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times 0$ and $0 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Then $I_{1}$ is $0, \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times 0$, $0 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}, \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} $.
(Step 3) Computing $I_{1} \oplus I_{2}$.
If all my procedure was correct, then it follows that $I_{1} \oplus I_{2}$ is $ I_{1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} $, $ I_{1} \oplus 0 $ where can be the following ideals $I_{1}$ is $0, \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times 0$, $0 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}, \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.
But this leads me to just 8 ideals. Im wondering if these are all the left ideals of the given ring and also how can I see them as matrices. As matrices by just doing try and error I obtained the following are ideals of the given ring seen as matrix ring. $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & 0  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, and last but not least the set of matrices
$$\Bigl\{ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \: | \: \mbox{such that} \: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{2} \: \mbox{and} \: a=b\Bigr\}.$$

Linking this to your other question as they are closely related.

It is not true that the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ is "basically the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{Z}_2&\mathbb{Z}_2\\ 0&\mathbb{Z}_2\end{array}\right)$", and Lam makes no such claim.
That matrix ring is noncommutative, since
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
0& 0\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
0&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
So it cannot possibly be "basically" the same as the commutative ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$.
Lam is looking at the general construction of rings of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
R&M\\0&S\end{array}\right)$$
where $R$ and $S$ are rings and $M$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule. He does so after four examples in 1.13(h), all of which are identified as subrings of $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R}(x))$. T
What he writes is that for these triangular rings:

It is conventient to identify $R$, $S$, and $M$ as subgroups [emphasis added] of $A$ (in the obvious way) and to think of $A$ as $R\oplus M\oplus S$. In terms of this decomposition, the multiplication in $A$ may be described by the following chart:
$$(1.16)\qquad\qquad\qquad\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
&R&M&S\\
\hline
R&R&M&0\\
M&0&0&M\\
S&0&0&S\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
From this it is immediately clear that $R$ is a left ideal, $S$ is a right ideal, and $M$ is a (square zero) ideal in $A$. Moreover, $R\oplus M$ and $M\oplus S$ are both ideals of $A$, with $A/(R\oplus M)\cong S$ and $A/(M\oplus S)\cong R$. Finally, $R\oplus S$ is a subring of $A$.

So when Lam says that "it is convenient... to think of $A$ as $R\oplus M\oplus S$" he is talking about the additive structure, not the multiplicative one, with the table labeled 1.16 giving how the multiplication goes.
If you have finitely many rings with unity $R_1,\ldots,R_n$, then every (left) ideal of $R_1\times\cdots\times R_n$ is of the form $J_1\times\cdots\times J_n$, with $J_i$ an (left) ideal of $R_i$. I'm sure we've proven this somewhere in this site before, but I cannot locate it right now: let $I$ be a left ideal of $R_1\times\cdots\times R_n$. Let $J_i$ be the projection of $I$ onto the $i$th component. Then $J_i$ is a left ideal of $R_i$, and clearly $I\subseteq J_1\times\cdots\times J_n$. Conversely, let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in J_1\times\cdots\times J_n$. For each $i$, pick an element $(b_1,\ldots,b_{i-1},a_i,b_{i+1},\ldots,b_n)\in I$ with $i$th component equal to $a_i$. Left-multiplying by the element that has $1_{R_{i}}$ in the $i$th component and $0$s elsewhere, we get an element that as $a_i$ in the $i$th component and zeros elsewhere, and which lies in $I$. Therefore, each $(0,\ldots,0,a_i,0,\ldots,0)$ lies in I$. Thus,
$$(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = (a_1,0,\ldots,0) + \cdots + (0,\ldots,0,a_i,0,\ldots,0) + \cdots + (0,\ldots,0,a_n)\in I.$$
This proves equality.
So the ideals you are looking for look like $J_1\times J_2\times J_3$; there are two choices for each $J_i$, so that gives a total of $8$. You got the right number by coincidence, since you were working with a different ring altogether.

@Arturo_Magidin First and foremost, thank you so much for your answer and detailed explanation Arturo.  It's a little bit funny because originally before posting this question I was looking for the ideals of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}{2} & \mathbb{Z}{2}  \
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$ But it was mentioned that the ideals of the matrix it was a direct consequence of the Lam's Proposition that I stated and the question was tagged as duplicate and therefore "erased". So by checking out that Lam result I tried to apply them to find the ideals I got confusing thinking ...

@Arturo_Magidin ....thinking that the ideals of this ring was the same as  $\mathbb{Z}{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}{2}$, which you already show me very clearly that is not the case. So my question is..... in order to find the ideals of the ring of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}{2} & \mathbb{Z}{2}  \
0 & \mathbb{Z}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$ my original aproach following Lam's proposition is correct? I'm afraid of asking again and being banned :(. Again, thank you so much for your help

@Cos Your first question was only "how do i find the left ideals of this" but in this version of the post you demonstrated that you were following previous solutions and came to an error in your thinking. Thanks too your writing, Arturo was able to diagnose it. That's totally fine (and not a duplicate.)

the question was tagged as duplicate and therefore "erased." I checked and I see that as of this time you deleted your own question.  You could (probably should) have edited that question instead of creating a new question.  Closure did not "erase" your question, you did.  I think it would be better if you undeleted it and left it as a duplicate, so it can lead others to similar answers.

@rschwieb Thank you very much for your clarification. Yes, you are right it was my mistake to say that the question was deleted by the forum, my bad.  I actually read your answer and Lam's book to solve my question, then I came to the steps I described in this question. I still have doubts about how to describe the ideals of that ring of matrices, so what would you recommend me to do? Edit the last question or make a new one explaining what I have done? I really don't want to bother anyone. Thank you

As things stand now, continue here, since this is where your question is most unique.  You said "ideals" without qualification... are you really asking about two-sided ideals or do you have further questions about Arturo's answer?

@rschwieb O.K. I want to compute the left ideals of $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}{2} & \mathbb{Z}{2}  \
0 & \mathbb{Z}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$ using the Lam Proposition that you've suggested.  I sketched out my work as it was originally asked in the question. And I'm also dubious about my work since the method is not leading me to the questions I found so far for that ring. Obvioulsy is my bad and not Lam's Propostition.

It seems to me you are not doing step 3 clearly.
We are agreed on step 1.  I'm going to use $F_2$ since it is easier to type and less ambiguous than $\mathbb Z_2$.
Then in step 3, there are two cases:
Case 1: $I_2=\{0\}$, whence $I_1$ can be any subspace of $F_2\times F_2$. There are five such subspaces.
Case 2: $I_2=F_2$, in which case the subspace $I_1$ has to contain $\{0\}\times F_2$, which rules out all but $\{0\}\times F_2$ and $F_2\times F_2$.
That's 7 left ideals.
Concretely they are

the two trivial ideals
$\begin{bmatrix}0&k\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}k&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\alpha\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ for $\alpha\in F_2$
$\begin{bmatrix}0&k\\0&k\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}k&k\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I'll let you work out $I_1$ and $I_2$ for each case.

Thank you so much! I think that for your case 1 in your Step 3 there are FOUR of those subspaces and not FIVE since there are only 4 subgroups of $F_{2} \times F_{2}$ right?

Also, the left 7 matrices that you propose are just $I_{2}$ right?  And you let me work out finding $I_{1}  \oplus I_{2}$, if I understand correctly? That means that the ideals I originaly I found correspond to $I_{1} \oplus I_{2}$ where $I_{1} = 0$ ??

@Cos Check again. There is one 0 dimensional subspace, three 1 dimensional subspaces, and one 2 dimensional subspace.

@cos I wrote literally the left ideals. I proposed three 1-dimensional left ideals and two 2-dimensional left ideals, and the trivial left ideals are zero dimensional and 3-dimensional.  They each have their own $I_1$ and $I_2$
